# In Extjs,How to get Json from a list response which also have null value of DateTime Data Types?

Tags: extjs

How can I get the json result from resonse of Ext.Ajax.request where we have also datatypes like DateTime.
Because if I get the null value of an int or string then Json retrives(decodes) it as 0 & null respectively.But if I have null value of DateTime field then it retrives the Blank Json.

Answer (score 1):

JSON does not provide direct support for Date values. It's up to your software *after* deserializing a JSON-encoded object to apply any semantics to the string and numeric values it finds inside the object.

In other words, your software has to "understand" what an object is supposed to be, somehow, and then apply its own interpretation when values are supposed to be re-interpreted as types other than string or numeric values. A Date could be encoded *either* as a string or a number, and in either case the value could be null.